# How can i get the profile picture of a user who have registered my website via the facebook social plugin

Tags: php, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have a registration plugin embeded via an iframe on my website, The registration plugin works fine , **I am also able to get the unique user_id of each user by using the following line of code in the signed_request file which can be located** [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/)

The line of code i use to get the user_id is: `$response["user_id"];`

Now that i have a unique id of each user, i want a way by which i can get the link to the profile image of that user, **i know i can get the thumbnail of the profile picutre**
using open graph,

But i am looking for a way by which i can get the link to the complete or the original profile picture, not the thumbnail.

Is there a way this can be done? Using open graph or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an API call to `/user_id/?fields=picture` using the access_token in the same signed_request

Comment: u mean graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxxx/?fields?=picture

Comment: Well, that again gave me the thumbnail of the image, not the full image

Comment: Then ask for `?fields=picture&type=large` - if you need the original you'll need to pull it from the Profile Pics album in the user's profile, in which case Jack's answer is the quickest way i can think of

Comment: can u suggest me  a way by which i can store the return link into a variable? @igy

Comment: i tried using $response["picture"]; but that did not help , can you suggest me a way?

Answer (score 2):

You need `user_photos` permissions first. Then something like this should do it:

```
SELECT cover_object_id FROM album WHERE owner=me() and type='profile'
```

*Substitute `me()` with the user you are querying for.*

It returns the photo object that you can then use to pull the full version from.

Comment: well where do i actually run that query?? new to this thing

Comment: @user1446599 it's a fql query, so your Facebook api should have no problem with that.